# Separate content of a cell by spaces

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet on `Google Docs`, in which are multiple columns. Each row contains all the data tags in one cell. So it is not separated under columns. How could I separate it into more cells? There is a separator between fields, 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in Column A, put the following in cell B1:

```
=arrayformula(split(A1:A, "    "))
```